# How can I call arbitrary function with arbitrary parameters from Solidity?

Tags: solidity, calldata

I am working on a voting library that allows members of a voting-DAO-like organization to vote on arbitrary actions. Security considerations (I know, arbitrary code execution is evil...) and efficiency (`this.call` is a `CALL` and not `JUMP` hence more expensive in terms of gas and not able to call `internal` functions) aside, how would I implement this without knowing the function to be voted upon at compile time of the voting library?

I know of this method:

```
bytes4 functionSig = bytes4(sha3("myFunc(uint256,address)"));
uint parameter1 = 123;
address parameter2 = 0xdf190dc7190dfba737d7777a163445b7fff16133;
// now wait for voting to be completed and upon positive outcome do:
this.call(functionSig, parameter1, parameter2);
```

but this requires me to know at least the number and types of parameters. How could I generalize this? I guess there must be something along the lines of

```
bytes callDataGeneratedSomehow = ...
this.call(callDataGeneratedSomehow)
```

But how can I generate the `callDataGeneratedSomehow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternate route:

1. Create an interface contract that both the main contract and "proposal" contracts inherit from.
2. In the fallback of a proposal contract, do what you want to do. Set any arguments explicitly here.
3. Deploy said contract.
4. Point the main contract at the proposal and use `.delegatecall()` to execute the proposal's code in the main contract's context.

There's probably cleaner/more elegant ways of doing this, but basically, rather than mess around with calldata, you can put up a separate contract and `.delegatecall()`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am not sure I understand the advantage of the joint base contract and the handling via fallback function (as this would just allow one type of vote per contract since they all fall back onto the same fallback function). This is my current best shot which is basically a modified VoteFactory from the Remix example file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/59c18f69d814a0335d6a9da15f907523

Comment: For each _different_ proposal, you create a separate contract inheriting from the same ancestor as the main contract. (You need to inherit so storage is laid out in the same way). When someone wants to make a new proposal, they can create a new contract and rewrite its fallback.

Comment: Ok I assume you're referring to the technique explored by Nick (https://gist.github.com/Arachnid/4ca9da48d51e23e5cfe0f0e14dd6318f) and Martin (http://martin.swende.se/blog/EVM-Assembly-trick.html). Got it now, thanks.